# Electron Forge error and dialog boxes intereactions

Tags: electron, popupwindow, electron-forge

When display error or dialog popup, how to block a parent window interarction until error or diaolog box closed? (I used default error and diaolog boxes using ipcRendere)

Block parent window intereaction until popup closed.